# re.fullmatch doesn't recognize matching pattern

Tags: python, python-re

I can't seem to get re.fullmatch to work. I inputed a pattern, then a string that matches that pattern and it seems to return as False. Chat GPT seems absolutley clueless about this for some reason as it keeps feeding me false information.

e.g.

```
import re
pattern = '[A-Z0-9a-z]{3}'

if re.fullmatch(pattern,'abc')== True:
    print("CORRECT")

else:
    print("NO")

pattern2 = '[a-z][a-z][a-z]'

if re.fullmatch(pattern2,'abc')== True:
    print("CORRECT")

else:
    print("NO")
```

In both these scenarios "NO" is being returned. How would I change the patterns in order to make it match with the string for example?

Comment: [fullmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) doesn't return a Boolean.

Comment: Just use `if re.fullmatch(pattern,'abc')`.  The function returns a _truthy_ value, but not the exact value `True`.